# Uploading file to S3 using SSE

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was trying to upload a file to s3 bucket but getting an " Access Denied" error. So checking using aws cli - It was found that we need to pass SSE kms key id to make it work

Bucket policy added with conditions: s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms and s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id: key-id. Below is my code which is still giving Access error.

Can someone please help?

```
public class FileUploadToAWSS3 {


    private static final String SUFFIX = "/";
    private static final String kms_cmk_id = "arn:aws:kms:";

    public void uploadFileToS3Bucket(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "access_key", 
                "secret_key");

        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        s3client.setEndpoint("https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");

        String bucketName = "my-bucket";
        s3client.createBucket(bucketName);

        String quarter1 = "root/Folder1";
        createFolder(bucketName, quarter1, s3client);
        String fileName = quarter1 + SUFFIX + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

         ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
         omd.setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType());
         omd.setContentLength(multipartFile.getSize());
         omd.setHeader("filename", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName,multipartFile.getInputStream(), omd)
                           .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private)
                            .withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(kms_cmk_id))); 
    }

    private void createFolder(String bucketName, String folderName, AmazonS3 client) {
                ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                metadata.setContentLength(0);

                InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);

                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                        folderName + SUFFIX, emptyContent, metadata);

                client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update as how it was resolved:-

Since a service instance (provisioned via cloud foundry) of S3 bucket was used; so bucket was created and specific create bucket command was not required.

Removed the code `s3client.createBucket(bucketName);` and it worked.